# Get list of params from SqlParameterCollection Parameters

Tags: c#, .net

How to get list of parameters passed to `SqlParameterCollection Parameters`? Is it possible to enumerate somehow them?

```
command.Connection = defaultConnection; 
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText =
    "INSERT into logs (ClientID, Msg, LogLevel, Date) VALUES (@ClientID, @Msg, @LogLevel, getdate())";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Msg", info);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogLevel", level);
```

Now I would like to get parameters as text from `command.Parameters`

UPD:

```
string s="";

    foreach (var param in command.Parameters)
        {
        s=s+ param ;  //how to get parameter with it's name in string type ?
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get parameters as text"? `command.Parameters` is just `IEnumerable<SqlParameter>` - so you can  do whatever you want with this collection (enumerate it, traverse or anything else)

Comment: this is very possible you will need to create a method that will take in the following `MethodName(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters` then inside your method create a `foreach(var item in parameters){ cmd.Parameters.Add(item)` Item being the parameters...

Comment: So, how to get all these parameters to one string?

Comment: did you try `foreach(SqlParameter param in command.Parameters) {...}` ?

Comment: Try `foreach (var param in command.Parameters){}`

Comment: do a simple google search on how to Enumerate a Collection of Sql Parameters.. which would be a string[] of parameters

Comment: Please add your desired output to the question - yes it's possible (and very easy) to enumerate them, but you elude to wanting "one string" - what would that string represent?  The names?  The values?  Both?  And _why_ do you want them?

Answer (score 7):

Updated to change the @ to $ for correct string interpolation:

```
var s = string.Join(",", cmd.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>().ToList().Select(p => $"{p.ParameterName}={p.Value}"));
```

Comment: genius answer, the Cast<>() did the trick from sqlparametercollection to list<sqlparameter>

Comment: Correct very good, but who wants to keep compatible with any type of database is better to cast to `DbParameter` instead of `SqlParameter`

Answer (score 2):

`Command.Parameters` is empty when you create an `SqlCommand` object. **SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command) is able to connect to DB and populate the Command.Parameters**, so that you will have just to set desired value for each parameter.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
                //instead of        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param",value);
                 command.Parameters["@Param"].Value = value;
```